# Adobe Illustrator CS6 Selection strange behavior

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I am facing a problem with selection in Illustrator 6. Sometimes I see selection handle without selecting any object. Although it doesn't select anything, but its quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

There are some graphical bugs in Illustrator. If you, for example, create a text box that's really small, the red '+' can remain on the screen even though you've deleted the text box. To see if it's a graphical bug - zoom in and out back again, this will remove graphical bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try an win+d (show desktop). Then restore ill. (Sometimes this solves some stuck floating popups too).

Or cut the culprit and paste it in front. (ctrl+x, ctrl+f).

Same thing here. Except zooming won't fix it, and if I select another object, the bounding box thingy includes the culprit.

Hope this helps!